# Iterating over list of namedtuples, selecting restaurants

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, namedtuple

I have a function that that returns restaurants with prices at or below a specified value. Here is my current code:

```
Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone menu')
Dish = namedtuple('Dish', 'name price calories')

r1 = Restaurant('Thai Dishes', 'Thai', '334-4433', [Dish('Mee Krob', 12.50, 500),
                                                Dish('Larb Gai', 11.00, 450)])
r2 = Restaurant('Taillevent', 'French', '01-44-95-15-01', 
            [Dish('Homard Bleu', 45.00, 750),
             Dish('Tournedos Rossini', 65.00, 950),
             Dish("Selle d'Agneau", 60.00, 850)])


collection =[r1,r2]


def Collection_is_cheap(C, price):
    result = []
    if not C:
       return ''
    else:
        for rest in C:
            for dish in rest.menu:
                if dish.price <= price:
                    result.append(rest)
    return result
```

But when I try to run it:

```
print(Collection_is_cheap(collection, 28))
```

I get is a long list of correct Restaurants, but repeated.

```
[Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=[Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=12.5, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=11.0, calories=450)]), Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=[Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=12.5, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=11.0, calories=450)]), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=[Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)]), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=[Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)]), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=[Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)]), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=[Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)])]
```

Whereas for the correct output it should only print the two restaurants once. How can I correct this, so that the function only returns:

```
[Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=[Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=12.5, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=11.0, calories=450)]), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=[Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)]
```

Comment: You don't check if `rest` is already in `result` before `append`ing it. Why not add some `break`s to skip items once the outcome is known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stop looping over the restaurant menu when you have a match; use `break` for this:

```
def Collection_is_cheap(C, price):
    result = []
    for rest in C:
        for dish in rest.menu:
            if dish.price <= price:
                result.append(rest)
                break  # stop the rest.menu loop, go to the next
    return result
```

Note that I removed the `if not C: return ''` part; it is better to not return different types of objects from a function.

Demo:

```
>>> def Collection_is_cheap(C, price):
...     result = []
...     for rest in C:
...         for dish in rest.menu:
...             if dish.price <= price:
...                 result.append(rest)
...                 break  # stop the rest.menu loop, go to the next
...     return result
... 
>>> print(Collection_is_cheap(collection, 28))
[Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=(Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=12.5, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=11.0, calories=450))), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=(Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)))]
```

Another approach is to use a *set* instead of a list; sets can only hold *unique objects*, so adding a restaurant more than once would not have any effect:

```
def Collection_is_cheap(C, price):
    result = set()
    for rest in C:
        for dish in rest.menu:
            if dish.price <= price:
                result.add(rest)
    return list(result)
```

For this to work, you'll also need to make the menu's use tuples, not lists:

```
r1 = Restaurant('Thai Dishes', 'Thai', '334-4433', (
    Dish('Mee Krob', 12.50, 500),
    Dish('Larb Gai', 11.00, 450)))

r2 = Restaurant('Taillevent', 'French', '01-44-95-15-01', ( 
    Dish('Homard Bleu', 45.00, 750),
    Dish('Tournedos Rossini', 65.00, 950),
    Dish("Selle d'Agneau", 60.00, 850)))

r3 = Restaurant('Pascal', 'French', '940-752-0107', (
    Dish('Escargots', 12.95, 250),
    Dish('Poached salmon', 18.50, 550),
    Dish("Rack of lamb", 24.00, 850),
    Dish("Marjolaine cake", 8.50, 950)))
```

so that they are entirely immutable, a requirement for using sets.

Another effect of using a `set` for collecting only unique restaurants, is that the order of restaurants returned may change, because sets are unordered. Instead, they hold objects in an implementation-dependent order that benefits testing for objects already being there, efficiently.

Demo; for this simple example with just two cheap restaurants the order *happens* to match that returned by the first version:

```
>>> def Collection_is_cheap(C, price):
...     result = set()
...     for rest in C:
...         for dish in rest.menu:
...             if dish.price <= price:
...                 result.add(rest)
...     return list(result)
... 
>>> print(Collection_is_cheap(collection, 28))
[Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=(Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=12.5, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=11.0, calories=450))), Restaurant(name='Pascal', cuisine='French', phone='940-752-0107', menu=(Dish(name='Escargots', price=12.95, calories=250), Dish(name='Poached salmon', price=18.5, calories=550), Dish(name='Rack of lamb', price=24.0, calories=850), Dish(name='Marjolaine cake', price=8.5, calories=950)))]
```

If you cannot use tuples for the menu sequences, and could not use the `break` trick for some reason, you'd have to use (slow and costly) list membership tests each time:

```
def Collection_is_cheap(C, price):
    result = []
    for rest in C:
        for dish in rest.menu:
            if dish.price <= price and rest not in result:
                result.append(rest)
    return result
```

This is slow and costly because Python will test each element in the list separately to see if `rest == element` is true, whereas with sets a trick called a *hash table* is used to quickly check if an object is already present, something that usually only takes a single computation check.

Comment: @martjin pieters.. Thanks for that amazing expalnation. I did end up making a silly mistake of not using break statement. But I see Sets would have been a better choice.